# Can we copy 2 objects without creating the mapping?

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to be able to deep copy 2 objects. The types are known only at runtime. I have a deep copy function that use reflection but I would like to use `AutoMapper` because it would be more robust.

I found

`Mapper.Map(item, itemInDatabase, item.GetType(), itemInDatabase.GetType());`

But I think you still need to create the mapping for their properties if it's a complex type.

Is there a way `AutoMapper` can copy 2 objects without creating the mapping before? It would only be based on the property names.

**EDIT**

The objects are the same but they are from different namespaces.
Basically, I want to copy an object from entity framework to an identical object but in a different edmx.

Comment: Are the properties for both objects the same, as in type and naming?

Comment: Yes. It's the same objects but from a different namespace

Comment: Do you have control over those 2 namespaces? If so, I would try to implement an interface.

Comment: Yes I have control but it's from entity framework. The interface would be huge. Do you think I do something wrong? All I wanna do is save an object in a different edmx.

Comment: If you're mapping entity framework proxy objects, you should use `DynamicMap` as that does not require you to know the types in advance.

Comment: I thought it was only for the dynamic type. I'm gonna try it right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing mapping with `Mapper.Initialize(c => c.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true)` before the map should do the trick, even for deep mappings (provided, of course, that your classes are structurally identical).

Comment: Perfect! The only problem I have now is with the properties with ICollection type. Is it supported by Automapper?

Comment: Could you amend your question so the case is more clear? Automapper has no problem mapping collection properties in my tests, even if the property is not using a concrete type but an interface. You mention you're using Entity Framework in a comment, that's also worth adding to your original question.

Comment: This will work, but just don't rename any properties without renaming the other. You'll silently get missing data. And I never recommend this approach unless you don't know the types at compile time. If you do know the types, specify CreateMap directly. Otherwise it's just lazy.